# how use phantomjs screenshot the whole page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I use phantomjs to screenshot a page,but can't screenshot buttom of the page.

```
 var height = page.evaluate(function()
 {
   window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;                                     
   }        
 );
```

value of the height is 33943,but the real value of scrollHeight is 44135.
 how can I load the whole page?

[the snapshot img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjdRV.png)

[the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDvzR.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can snapshot your page by:

```
var WebPage = require('webpage');
page = WebPage.create();
page.open('http://www.example.com');
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
   page.render('screenshot.png');
   phantom.exit();
}
```

Not sure why you need to calculate the height of your page.

Comment: I tried you method,still can't load bottom of the page.  I calculated the height to see whether bottom of the page was loaded. You can see I upload the images.

Comment: Is the content dynamically loaded **after** the page is loaded? If yes, you have to add delay before you capture the page.

Comment: The content is not dynamically load.Some pages can screenshot the whole content,but when the content is too long,the snapshot is not whole.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to took a screenshot of the whole page by setting the page property.

For example:

```
var width = 1024, height = 768;
page.property("viewportSize", {'width': width, 'height': height});
```

The one on the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) `page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };` might not be updated because it returned the warning :

> **warn**: Using page.viewportSize = ...; is not supported. Use page.property('viewportSize', ...) instead. See the README file for more examples of page#property.